Is there any use for the file "WEB-INF/manager.xml" in Tomcat 9's default "host-manager" web application?
I am running Tomcat 9 (tomcat-9.0.96-1.fc41.noarch) and have also installed the package for the Tomcat administrative webapps (tomcat-admin-webapps-9.0.96-1.fc41.noarch).
The host-manager webapp comes with file host-manager/WEB-INF/manager.xml. That file declares filtering based on IP, among others:
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager"
         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" >

  <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                   sameSiteCookies="strict" />

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />

  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>

</Context>

This is basically the same as the file host-manager/META-INF/context.xml of the same web application, except for the root tag attributes:
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >

  <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                   sameSiteCookies="strict" />

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />

  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/> 

</Context>

The file host-manager/META-INF/context.xml is official (Defining a context.
However, host-manager/WEB-INF/manager.xml seems to serve no purpose (is it even read by anything?), it does not even appear in the Jakarta Servlet Specification is it just there for historical reasons?
